# Which HTTP headers needed for connection throw Proxy with Basic Authentication?

Tags: php, symfony, http, proxy, header

```
$curlClient = new HttpBrowser(HttpClient::create());
$url        = 'http://example.com';

$response   = $curlClient->request('GET', $url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Proxy' => '10.10.10.10:3128',
                'Proxy-Authorization' => 'Basic user:pass'
            ],
        ]);
```

I try to connect to example.com via proxy with Basic authentication.

Similar command in Curl looks like

```
curl -x 10.10.10.10:3128 --proxy-user user:pass -i http://example.com
```

What headers do I need to send ?

Comment: `user:pass` needs to be base64 encoded, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Protocol, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization#directives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy server in Symfony 5 should be configured  just adding parameter proxy with correct  Optional (Proxy user, proxy password), proxy IP, proxy port

```
        $curlClient     = new HttpBrowser(HttpClient::create(
        [
            'proxy' => 'http://proxy_username:proxy_password@proxy_ip:proxy_port'
        ]
    ));
$url            = 'http://example.com';

$response       = $curlClient->request('GET', $url);
```